# My MVC project doesn't work after deploying it in the web server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project that uses a fullcalendar jQuery. The project runs perfectly in Visual Studio without any error. After I deployed the project to a web server, I get this error:

```
Get http://.... 404 (not found)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaw1X.jpg)

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and web server 2012.

The error occurs in this part of the code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/event/GetEvents",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                events.push({
                            eventID: v.EventID,
                            title: v.Subject,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.Start),
                            end: v.Finish != null ? moment(v.Finish) : null,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                });
            })

            GenerateCalender(events);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    })
```

failed all the time. This is my first time to work with ASP.NET MVC.

Is there any specific way to deploy the project in the server or is there any thing missing to be added? Or do I need to change some settings on the server?

Comment: A blurry image of text like that is *not* going to help others help you. If you are getting errors, post them as text in either a quoteblock or codefence.

Comment: Get http://event/GetEvents 404 (not found). Getevents is an action method in the controller event

Comment: Use the [edit] feature if you are trying to replace the image with the actual text.

Comment: Can we see your `EventController` and the `GetEvents` action?

Comment: Is your project in the root of webspace?  So http://yourserver/event/GetEvents is a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should render right js files in BundleConfig.cs, maybe you can publish your website with all files like Controllers, Views, Models etc.

[image: sample BundleConfig.cs configuration]
[image: sample publish options]
[image: sample publish profile]